# Store Program code in database with right syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, web, ace-editor

I have a college project in which i am using ace editor on a webpage. https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace

Ace editor customizes  tag to look like a editor. I can extract its value usign jquery .val() function or editor API but the source code looses its syntax.
For example if the code is :

```
System.out.printls("Enter number");
int value = ScannnerObj.nextInt();
```

The extracted values looks like :

System.out.printls("Enter number");int value = ScannnerObj.nextInt(); //All in one line

I have to extract this value from editor and save it in database I am using Django for it.
Later I also want to retrieve it in such that the Program Syntax is not altered.

Can anyone tell my correct way to achieve this. I am missing some link in here.
Thanx in advance :)

Comment: How are you trying to confirm that the extracted values don't have line breaks? Normal html will not display line breaks when viewed through the browser as plain text.

Comment: I pass the extracted value using POST method the Django View which handles it and saves it in database.I then get the value from database and view it using python interactive shell

Comment: I'm with Kevin--if you're printing the data back out in HTML the line breaks won't display.  Wrap the output in a `<pre>` tag, if that's the case.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, does the data appear to have line breaks when POSTing the data to Django?  Are you using a native method of the Ace editor that might be stripping away line breaks?

Comment: i use this code to extract data :
var myDiv = document.getElementById("editor");
var program = myDiv.textContent;

Comment: @CaseyKinsey : I tried using <pre> tag too but somehow line breaks get strips off. :(

Comment: Have you looked in the database itself to see what is stored there?

Comment: As a definitive test, try using a textarea. `var myDiv = document.getElementById("editor"); var program = myDiv.textContent; $("<textarea />").val(program).appendTo("body");`

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle showing that your way of extracting the text should be preserving the line break. Either you are losing it between the server and database, or you aren't losing it at all and you just aren't outputting it in a way that shows line breaks. http://jsfiddle.net/rKx4Q/1/

Comment: Ok here is somethings interesting what I did.
I saves a program into database using Django Admin panel and enclosed the program using <pre> tags and syntax is retained in database and also while outputing in HTML :)
I will slowly debug every interface through which data passes through. I guess data is not getting extracted properly from <div>

Comment: Ok guys I found the solution for it :)
use the following code to render ace editor
editor = ace.edit("editor"); 
not
var editor = ace.edit("editor"); //(not to write var)
I will write it as answer when Stackoverflow lets me answer my own question after few hours due to less reput :P

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I found the solution for it :) use the following code to render ace editor

```
editor = ace.edit("editor"); 
not 
var editor = ace.edit("editor"); //(not to write var)
```